# Hibernate bytecode instrumentation fetching issue

Tags: hibernate, jpa, fetch, lazy-evaluation, instrumentation

I applied Hibernate bytecode instrumentation for a class with maven-antrun-plugin using `org.hibernate.tool.instrument.javassist.InstrumentTask`. Class has lazy `@OneToOne` relationship as shown below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableName", schema = "...", catalog = "...")
public class FirstClass {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private long id;

  @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "secondClassId")
  private SecondClass secondClass;
//accessors
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tableName", schema = "...", catalog = "...")
public class SecondClass {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private long id;

//accessors
}
```

When I try to fetch property `secondClass` with Criteria or jpql I see that "secondClass" data is retrieved, after I look at the debug and there is no secondClass data(but should be).
Query:

```
SELECT FC FROM FirstClass FC JOIN FETCH FC.secondClass
```

Why does it happens so? Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Post the method calling the query, and where you are checking for the "secondClass", and where it is null.

Comment: It is just an example, I have this problem in enterprise app and I can't post it here and there is no sense to do it. I designed  
analogous code/situation.

Comment: "no sense to do it" ? well there is every sense for people to see at what point in the transaction you are checking the fields for values. Is the object "managed", "detached", or in what state? without basic info you won't get an accurate reply

Comment: Sorry and thank you for explanation! I check it in the controller's method, there is direct call of dao's method, which is not annotated with `@Transactional`, so there is no transaction(no session)